# batch convert weblinks by appending characters

Tags: url-modification

is there any easy way to batch convert links by appending characters and provide batch output.

As shown in this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DActh.png

The inputs will be given in batch as  separate lines , and the output expected is batch in separate lines..

I do not have any programming background, so appreciate if you can direct me to any application that can easily do it without me writing the code  else you can give me advice. I do have windows and MS office, so if there is something already in there, that can do it by writing a simple program, also let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to achieve that. There are many online tools where you can transform your data without having tools installed locally.

I prepared an expression for you here: https://regex101.com/r/l1ZUHZ/1

Programmatically a solution could look like:

```
/^(http.*)/![]($1)/gm
```

---

A second example, that matches the protocol and replaces it with `https`: https://regex101.com/r/sufiUI/1

```
/^https?(:.*)/![](https$1)/gm
```

---

Sorting is a different task. I suppose you can do that in Excel for example. There's also a [`sort` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sort) available in Windows.
To sort in reverse order you need the `/r` option.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much joe, can you please modify so that the output is in reverse order, for example my row 1 becomes last row and vice versa.

Comment: Can you please edit to read and write as "HTTPS" instead of HTTP. also i understand that i can save this URL and use it in future.

Comment: thank you, i see that there are some examples populated, is it possible to keep it as blank and remove the examples, so I can paste my link directly.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.